# Woocomerce - вывод отдельных элементов товара

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Вот такой код

```
<?php 
 echo do_shortcode('[product_page]');
?>
```

выводит карточку товара вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но у меня своя верстка каталога

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть мне нужно получить отдельно:
Название товара, цену, описание, миниатюру. Слева будут фильтры. То есть мне нужно убрать Вывод формы поиска и список "Страницы". Как это сделать?

Comment: Идите читайте про хуки https://wp-kama.ru/id_6680/kak-rabotayut-huki-v-wordpress-filtry-i-sobytiya.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $product = wc_get_product();
    $id = $product->get_id();
    $title = $product->get_title($id);
    $price = $product->get_price($id);
    echo $id;
    echo $title;
    echo $price;
?>
```